# String Replace in Smarty

Tags: string, replace, smarty

May I know, how can I replace all elements within `"("` with `" "`.

example:

```
this is (test) => this is
```

Answer (score 6):

Have you tried this?

```
{$var|replace:'value':'new_value'}
```

Followed [this article](http://www.smarty.net/docs/en/language.modifier.replace.tpl)

Or the regex str_replace?

```
{$var|regex_replace:"/[\r\t\n]/":" "}
```

Found [here](http://www.smarty.net/docsv2/en/language.modifier.regex.replace.tpl)

Answer (score 0):

Ron van der Heijden's response was very useful. I needed to do the same thing but with square brackets and my solution is below. I used an [online regex generator](http://txt2re.com/) to help me with the regex part.

```
{$var|regex_replace:"(\\[.*?\\])":""}
```

Answer (score 0):

A little more advanced replacing:

```
{$ptions_data = $c.options|replace:"value=\"{$c.content}\"":"value=\"{$c.content}\" selected=\"selected\""}

{$ptions_data}

{$tabs_data = $c.tabs|replace:"id=\"tab-{$c.content}\" class=\"tabs\" style=\"display:none\"":"id=\"tab-{$c.content}\" class=\"tabs\" style=\"display:block\""}

{$tabs_data}
```